# ICC vs Repeated Measures ANOVA to Justify Multilevel Model

Tags: mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, intraclass-correlation

I have heard of using ICCs to determine if there is variability to justify using a multilevel (i.e., mixed effects, hierarchical) model. However, I've recently seen studies examine whether there is a statistically significant difference across trials with repeated measures ANOVA. Is this approach common/justified?

My intuition is that using RM ANOVA is suboptimal but I'm curious to hear others' thoughts.